# Как сделать ссылки ЧПУ

Tags: .htaccess

А как это http://site.com/index.php?name=price
сделать в это http://site.com/price

Comment: А что значит "Сделан вопросом"?

Comment: @knes Вопрос был задан в качестве ответа на на подобный ворос!

Answer (score 1):

[Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/).

> The Mod Rewrite Generator can be used to turn dynamic URLs into search engine friendly static URLs. Static URLs typically rank better in search engines than long complex dynamic URLs with lots of parameters, they are easier to index in the first place and they're also friendlier looking to the end user.