# Настройка mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Доброго времени суток!) Не могу разобраться как организовать вот такое дело: 
на сайте контент разбит на языки и города. Вопрос- как преобразовать запрос вида
/Russian в
?lang=Russian
а /Muhosransk в
?sity=Muhosransk 
при том что языков около сотни, городов примерно 700. 
и возможны комбинированные запросы типа /Russian/Muhosransk/ => ?lang=Russian&sity=Muhosransk
Для каждого из них делать условие как-то расточительно)
Так же не хотелось бы делать урлы вида lang/Russian, sity/Muhosransk ну или l_Russian/, s_Muhosransk/. Ну и тем более подтягивать данные с бд и делать редирект на php. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли это и если да, то хотя бы подтолкните на мысль)) Заранее всем огромнейшее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не получится вот так вот просто.

Либо тебе придется для КАЖДОГО урла задавать соответствие, поэтому лучше /lang/ru -> ?lang=ru , выставить язык и дальше все равно лучше /city/Muhosransk -> ?city=Muhosransk
только в таком случае можно так переводить.

либо вариант номер 2: делать

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(ru|en)/([a-z0-9\-/]+)?$           index.php?m=$2&lang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-/]+)?$               index.php?m=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
```

Если первым встречается ru или en, то ru en выводим в ?lang, а все, что за ними идет в переменную m... вся остальная обработка уже на стороне php скрипта.

Наверное в вашем случае это будет самое оптимальное и безболезненное.

Comment: thunder, большое спасибо)

Comment: да пожалуйста) "примите" ответ, если правильный ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/).

> The Mod Rewrite Generator can be used to turn dynamic URLs into search engine friendly static URLs. Static URLs typically rank better in search engines than long complex dynamic URLs with lots of parameters, they are easier to index in the first place and they're also friendlier looking to the end user.

Отвечено было [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148723/htaccess-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%BF%D1%83?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=148739#148739). 
И еще в куче мест до этого. Попробуйте поискать по запросу 'mod_rewrite' 99% вопросов - по ЧПУ.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, пригодится)